# How to add profile picture on django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been trying to add a profile picture to users but the file seems to be "unknown" so I think the error is on the profile.html but I dont know how to fix it.

views.py

```
    def profile(request, username=None):
      if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        user_posts = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
      else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
      }
      return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

models.py

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank="True", default="default.png")

      def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

profile.hmtl

```
    <h2 class="account-heading">{{ post_owner.username }}</h2>
    <img class="account-img" src="{{ user.profile.profile_pics.url }}" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;margin-left: 15px;margin-right:15px;">
    <h2 class="account-heading">{{ post_owner.first_name }}</h2>
```

btw I have pillow installed, but I will add the settings.py and urls.y so that you van see it:)

views.py

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
     path('', include('home.urls')),
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
   ]
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo in your question but you set `MEDIA_URL` in your views.py yet in your urls.py you reference `settings.MEDIA_URL` not the `MEDIA_URL` declared in your views.py.

Comment: @RedCricket What do you mean? am I missing to import something?

Comment: No I didn't say you were missing an import.  I said you are not using the `MEDIA_URL` your declared in your views.py.  Why don't you set the `MEDIA_URL` in your settings.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define field as `profile_pic` but you try to reach `profile_pics` in your html file. Change the `src` attribute of `img` element like this:

```html
src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"
```